# Firefox Google search redirect virus

Tags: firefox, virus, malware

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What to do if my computer is infected by a virus or a malware?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/what-to-do-if-my-computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware)

Can Anybody suggest me a tool or something else to solve 'Google search redirect virus' ?
i tried Malwarebytes' Anti-Malware and avira antivirus but i already have this problem.
my search results when i search something in google redirect me to unknown sites and unregisterd domains .
I have this problem both in FF4 and FF3.*

Comment: its not duplicate because i did try Malwarebytes' Anti-Malware But it did not help me.

Comment: Have you tried all the other options listed in that question, Spybot S&D, Microsoft Security Essentials, scanning using a LiveCD and other options?

Comment: I did Try Spybot and Microsoft Security Essentials , but i didn't try Scanning using liveCd ,

Comment: How was this marked a duplicate to the much more general virus question? Not every virus has the same removal instructions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This "Google redirect virus" has been named "Backdoor.Tidserv" by Symantec.

They have a page about it and they offer a free removal tool, I recommend you try that.

This will happen in ALL browsers as the malware is local and unrelated to your browser.

[Symantec Tidserv Removal Tool](http://www.symantec.com/security_response/writeup.jsp?docid=2010-090608-3309-99)

I hope this helps you get rid of it!

Answer (score 2):

This may be malware, but hijacking the search may also be the result of altering the DNS locally (hosts file) or on your router.

What about internet explorer/chrome? Do they have the problem as well?
If yes -> go check your hosts file first: c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts. If www.google.com is listed, that's not ok. Also check your router's DNS settings. Some malware breaks into routers to change the dns settings. And that may be a good explanation why malwarebytes/avira can't find anything.

Answer (score 1):

I actually called Microsoft support on this for my brothers laptop and they have a hotfix as well. It was just a patch we downloaded from the internet on their support site. The phone tech walked me through it once, and I did it once by myself. Unfortunately, I only bookmarked it on my brother's machine.

Comment: where can i ask for hotfix ?

Comment: You could try this http://www.microsoft.com/security/pc-security/malware-removal.aspx or just go through the usual MS support site: http://support.microsoft.com/common/international.aspx I connected by phone with support for the OS on the issue but I'm not sure how I navigated to it, starting with the OS support, I suppose. If you find the number of the hotfix, post it here please.